# Interchanging limits without Fubini/Tonelli?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a problem and have reached the following

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\log x)^{n}}{n!}\;dx
$$

and I'd like to interchange the integral and the sum so that I have

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x\log x)^{n}}{n!}\;dx
$$

in order to solve the problem. After doing a bit of research, I've found the Fubini/Tonelli theorems mentioned a fair bit on the web and on MSE. There are some really good answers on this site, however:

The problem I'm working on is for an introductory real analysis course. We've not touched measure theory and are discouraged from using results outside of the course that we have not proved.

I'm curious to know whether for this particular case one could justify the interchanging of the integral and the sum without measure theory?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\log x)^{n}}{n!}$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll do this. If the series uniformly converges, what result would we be evoking to interchange the integral and summation? (sorry if silly question). My intuition would be that because the sequence inside the series is uniformly convergent, then its limiting function is continuous...would that then be enough?

Comment: have you heard of term by term integration? if you prove that a series is uniformly convergent and its terms are all continuous in [a,b] then the integration and summation are interchangeable.

Comment: Ah! Wow, of course. Thank you very much.